# Combine IE hacks with JQuery css()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I need to adjust an elements height for IE 7. Usually I would do this in my external style sheet by using the hack `\9` eg:

```
#container {
 height: 200px\9;
}
```

But this particular height is generated by JQuery, eg:

```
$('#container').css({'height': containerheight});
```

For IE, I needed to add the hack so I tried:

```
var iecontainerheight = height + 'px\9;';
$('#container').css({'height': iecontainerheight});
```

But this does not work.

Does anyone know how to correctly include that hack with css()?

Comment: if you want to change the height using script why don't you do the browser detection and then assign the correct height

Comment: what does `\9` do? I've never had problems with height in IE7

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `;` from 'px\9;'. It's invalid.

And also try this:

```
var iecontainerheight = height + '\9';
$('#container').css({'height': iecontainerheight});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try detecting browser using jQuery. It will apply to IE browser only.

```
if (m_BrowserName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" && m_BrowserVersion.indexOf("MSIE 7.0") > 0){
      //your css goes here    
}
```